# Submit New Product Using Amazon Marketplace WebService

Tags: amazon-web-services, soa, marketplace

I am trying to add a new product using MWS, Here's the XML I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AmazonEnvelope>
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>my merchant id</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Product>
<SKU>SKU-TEST-123</SKU>
<StandardProductID>
<Type>ISBN</Type>
<Value>9781235467899</Value>
</StandardProductID>
<LaunchDate>2010-02-17T20:15:58.309+02:00</LaunchDate>
<ReleaseDate>2010-02-17T20:15:58.309+02:00</ReleaseDate>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>My Product</Title>
<Description>Product Description ...</Description>
</DescriptionData>
</Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I got error in the processing report:

```
<Result>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
<ResultMessageCode>8060</ResultMessageCode>
<ResultDescription>The Product with SKU [SKU-TEST-123] cannot be matched to an existing product for the following reason: (NEW is not allowed; ). For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/errorcode/8060</ResultDescription>
<AdditionalInfo>
<SKU>SKU-TEST-123</SKU>
</AdditionalInfo>
</Result>
```

I should be able to upload new products, no? Is there any restrictions to the SKU?

Comment: Have you gotten this working? I've just started working with Amazon Marketplace API and it sucks.

Comment: For me it was a problem with the account itself, we fixed it by calling the support.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the OperationType immedately after the MessageID. For example:

```
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>SKU-TEST-123</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ISBN</Type>
        <Value>9781235467899</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>My product</Title>
        <Brand>My brand</Brand>
        <Description>My description</Description>
        <MSRP currency="USD">24.03</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>blah</Manufacturer>
        <SearchTerms>foo</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bar</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>xyzzy</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
```

Comment: From where we can see those list of paramters ?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with a Text Tab Delimited file upload... all the ones that come back with that error seem to be sold books, or books that I am trying to remove from the database.. But they still seem to come off anyways. Try searching for your sku here https://sellercentral.amazon.com/myi/search/ItemSummary.amzn?ref_=sc_site_map_smless_ezdpc_gui_inv&refsrc=sm
Maybe the files have uploaded and amazon is just spittng out a strange error message at you?